# Node specified with setNode() method forwards read request to other nodes

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am trying to read data present in a specific cassandra (4)  node, using Datastax driver version 4.13. I have read [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/266609/read-from-partition-in-local-cassandra-node-only) post, which supposedly works for driver versions 3.x

I have modified my code as best I can for driver version 4.x. The operative part of the code looks like

```
BoundStatement bs= psGetAllOptimizedModule.bind(imei,year,month,startDate,endDate)
            .setTracing(true)
            .setNode(localNode).setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_ONE).setPageSize(pageSize);
    Instant start=Instant.now();
    ResultSet rs = session.execute(bs);
```

While the query is indeed directed to the specified node, the node then is sometimes forwarding requests to other nodes,  even though the data is present on the specified node.

I wanted to check if this is at all possible in cassandra, and if so, what I need to do differently.

Update: As requested, the information asked for has been added to a pastebin  [here](https://pastecode.dev/s/XfvcgdKl5G), as its too long to add to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The `Statement.setNode()` API does in fact restrict the request such that the driver will ignore the load balancing policy and only execute the statement on the specified node.

However, the symptom you described indicates to me that the query cannot be satisfied by just one node so it has to request data from other replicas despite setting the consistency to `LOCAL_ONE`.

In fact the name `psGetAllOptimizedModule` suggests to me that you are trying to retrieve more than just one record so it makes sense that the coordinating node needs to request the data from other nodes.

You can easily confirm that this is the case by running the query locally on the Cassandra node with tracing enabled and consistency set to `LOCAL_ONE`. Cheers!

Comment: I am indeed trying to get multiple records from a single partition. The table is incrementally repaired every day. That aside,tracing is enabled, and  querying node1 is sometimes answered by node 1, sometimes by node 2 & 3. Similarly, querying node2 results in querying node 2 sometimes, but also node 1 & node 3. 

Isn't local_one supposed to prevent cross-node queries? Even if the query can't be satisfied by a particular node, it should return an empty set - thats my desired behaviour. As mentioned in the qestion, the only effect of setNode() is to always initially query the desired node.

Comment: I have tried to run the query from the cqlsh terminal by turning tracing on, and setting consistency level to local_one. But the session still sometimes hits other nodes, and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: One other question - will changing the load balancing policy help? I'm finding it difficult to find documentation/examples which tells me how I can change/set Load Balancign Policy in DataStax 4.x.

Comment: "But the session still sometimes hits other nodes, and sometimes it doesn't." Like I said, the coordinator has to query other nodes other than "local" because the requested data isn't available on the local node. Cheers!

Comment: How can the  exact same data sometimes be available from the local node, and sometimes not? I am happy to share the trace logs.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. You may think the data exists on a node but it doesn't. You're not comparing apples-for-apples because the data in "sometimes available" is not the same data as "sometimes not" -- they are two different things. You need to analyse the data so you can see why they are not all available on just one node. Cheers!

Comment: It has nothing to do with "thinking". The exact same query was fired 10 times. The exact same result came every time. 7 times out of 10, the same node was hit. 3 times out of 10, another node was hit. This is a 3 node cluster with a replication factor of 3. Clearly, something is not working the way it is supposed to, or our understanding is wrong. 

On another note, I was hoping for performance improvement if the data came from the same node, which hasn't happened - the fetch times are not statistically better  - something like 6-7 seconds for a synchronous  call on 300K rows.

Comment: Then prove it.  Update your original question with (1) the table schema, (2) sample data, (3) query you are running, (4) list of nodes with corresponding token assignments. You'll have to provide the real data in (2) since I need to map the partition keys to the replicas otherwise I won't be able to replicate it. Cheers!

Comment: Added the information in the pastebin. When & if we get to the bottom of this, we can modify the question to present the details correctly.